# Why is jQuery Datables's FixedHeader feature not working for this simple table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I've tried everything and I can't see why it doesn't work, its basically exactly what they provide and an example on their documentation

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.0/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js" ></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        fixedHeader: true,
        paging:false,

        searching:false
    } );
} );
</script>

</head>
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Name</th><th>Position</th><th>Office</th><th>Age</th><th>Start date</th><th>Salary</th></tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr><td>Tiger Nixon</td><td>System Architect</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>61</td><td>2011/04/25</td><td>$320,800</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Garrett Winters</td><td>Accountant</td><td>Tokyo</td><td>63</td><td>2011/07/25</td><td>$170,750</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Ashton Cox</td><td>Junior Technical Author</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>66</td><td>2009/01/12</td><td>$86,000</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Cedric Kelly</td><td>Senior Javascript Developer</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>22</td><td>2012/03/29</td><td>$433,060</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Airi Satou</td><td>Accountant</td><td>Tokyo</td><td>33</td><td>2008/11/28</td><td>$162,700</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Brielle Williamson</td><td>Integration Specialist</td><td>New York</td><td>61</td><td>2012/12/02</td><td>$372,000</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Herrod Chandler</td><td>Sales Assistant</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>59</td><td>2012/08/06</td><td>$137,500</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Rhona Davidson</td><td>Integration Specialist</td><td>Tokyo</td><td>55</td><td>2010/10/14</td><td>$327,900</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Colleen Hurst</td><td>Javascript Developer</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>39</td><td>2009/09/15</td><td>$205,500</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Sonya Frost</td><td>Software Engineer</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>23</td><td>2008/12/13</td><td>$103,600</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Jena Gaines</td><td>Office Manager</td><td>London</td><td>30</td><td>2008/12/19</td><td>$90,560</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Quinn Flynn</td><td>Support Lead</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>22</td><td>2013/03/03</td><td>$342,000</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Charde Marshall</td><td>Regional Director</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>36</td><td>2008/10/16</td><td>$470,600</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Haley Kennedy</td><td>Senior Marketing Designer</td><td>London</td><td>43</td><td>2012/12/18</td><td>$313,500</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td><td>Regional Director</td><td>London</td><td>19</td><td>2010/03/17</td><td>$385,750</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Michael Silva</td><td>Marketing Designer</td><td>London</td><td>66</td><td>2012/11/27</td><td>$198,500</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Paul Byrd</td><td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td><td>New York</td><td>64</td><td>2010/06/09</td><td>$725,000</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Gloria Little</td><td>Systems Administrator</td><td>New York</td><td>59</td><td>2009/04/10</td><td>$237,500</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Bradley Greer</td><td>Software Engineer</td><td>London</td><td>41</td><td>2012/10/13</td><td>$132,000</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Dai Rios</td><td>Personnel Lead</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>35</td><td>2012/09/26</td><td>$217,500</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Jenette Caldwell</td><td>Development Lead</td><td>New York</td><td>30</td><td>2011/09/03</td><td>$345,000</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Yuri Berry</td><td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td><td>New York</td><td>40</td><td>2009/06/25</td><td>$675,000</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Caesar Vance</td><td>Pre-Sales Support</td><td>New York</td><td>21</td><td>2011/12/12</td><td>$106,450</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Doris Wilder</td><td>Sales Assistant</td><td>Sidney</td><td>23</td><td>2010/09/20</td><td>$85,600</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Angelica Ramos</td><td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td><td>London</td><td>47</td><td>2009/10/09</td><td>$1,200,000</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Gavin Joyce</td><td>Developer</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>42</td><td>2010/12/22</td><td>$92,575</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Jennifer Chang</td><td>Regional Director</td><td>Singapore</td><td>28</td><td>2010/11/14</td><td>$357,650</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Brenden Wagner</td><td>Software Engineer</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>28</td><td>2011/06/07</td><td>$206,850</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Fiona Green</td><td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>48</td><td>2010/03/11</td><td>$850,000</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Shou Itou</td><td>Regional Marketing</td><td>Tokyo</td><td>20</td><td>2011/08/14</td><td>$163,000</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Michelle House</td><td>Integration Specialist</td><td>Sidney</td><td>37</td><td>2011/06/02</td><td>$95,400</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Suki Burks</td><td>Developer</td><td>London</td><td>53</td><td>2009/10/22</td><td>$114,500</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Prescott Bartlett</td><td>Technical Author</td><td>London</td><td>27</td><td>2011/05/07</td><td>$145,000</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Gavin Cortez</td><td>Team Leader</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>22</td><td>2008/10/26</td><td>$235,500</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Martena Mccray</td><td>Post-Sales support</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>46</td><td>2011/03/09</td><td>$324,050</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Unity Butler</td><td>Marketing Designer</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>47</td><td>2009/12/09</td><td>$85,675</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Howard Hatfield</td><td>Office Manager</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>51</td><td>2008/12/16</td><td>$164,500</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Hope Fuentes</td><td>Secretary</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>41</td><td>2010/02/12</td><td>$109,850</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Vivian Harrell</td><td>Financial Controller</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>62</td><td>2009/02/14</td><td>$452,500</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Timothy Mooney</td><td>Office Manager</td><td>London</td><td>37</td><td>2008/12/11</td><td>$136,200</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Jackson Bradshaw</td><td>Director</td><td>New York</td><td>65</td><td>2008/09/26</td><td>$645,750</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Olivia Liang</td><td>Support Engineer</td><td>Singapore</td><td>64</td><td>2011/02/03</td><td>$234,500</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Bruno Nash</td><td>Software Engineer</td><td>London</td><td>38</td><td>2011/05/03</td><td>$163,500</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Sakura Yamamoto</td><td>Support Engineer</td><td>Tokyo</td><td>37</td><td>2009/08/19</td><td>$139,575</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Thor Walton</td><td>Developer</td><td>New York</td><td>61</td><td>2013/08/11</td><td>$98,540</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Finn Camacho</td><td>Support Engineer</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>47</td><td>2009/07/07</td><td>$87,500</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Serge Baldwin</td><td>Data Coordinator</td><td>Singapore</td><td>64</td><td>2012/04/09</td><td>$138,575</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Zenaida Frank</td><td>Software Engineer</td><td>New York</td><td>63</td><td>2010/01/04</td><td>$125,250</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Zorita Serrano</td><td>Software Engineer</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>56</td><td>2012/06/01</td><td>$115,000</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Jennifer Acosta</td><td>Junior Javascript Developer</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>43</td><td>2013/02/01</td><td>$75,650</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Cara Stevens</td><td>Sales Assistant</td><td>New York</td><td>46</td><td>2011/12/06</td><td>$145,600</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Hermione Butler</td><td>Regional Director</td><td>London</td><td>47</td><td>2011/03/21</td><td>$356,250</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Lael Greer</td><td>Systems Administrator</td><td>London</td><td>21</td><td>2009/02/27</td><td>$103,500</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Jonas Alexander</td><td>Developer</td><td>San Francisco</td><td>30</td><td>2010/07/14</td><td>$86,500</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Shad Decker</td><td>Regional Director</td><td>Edinburgh</td><td>51</td><td>2008/11/13</td><td>$183,000</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Michael Bruce</td><td>Javascript Developer</td><td>Singapore</td><td>29</td><td>2011/06/27</td><td>$183,000</td></tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code should look more like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "fixedHeader": true,
    "paging":false,

    "searching":false
} );
} );
```

You need quotation marks around them.

Source:
datatables.net